# problems in using vertex snapping in unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning unity3d 5.3.4 and I am having problems in using vertex snapping. I want to move my background. For that I duplicated my background and then use **"V"** key for vertex snapping. But as I press **"V"** key my cursor gets locked and I can't do anything.I tried to manually place duplicated copy of background side by side but in gameplay it is not working properly. Is there any other way to do vertex snapping in version 5 of unity?

Comment: Ypu should probably post your code :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to record an animated GIF of the problem? Otherwise, there isn't much here for people to work off of.

Comment: Have you selected the correct widget in the scene view to move a gameobject? If you are currently moving the camera around or something, it doesn't work. Also the properties of the vertex snapping change depending on where on the gameobjects you grabbed(near the corners or the center)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I am using a touchscreen laptop, the solution for me was to press "V" as you normally would for vertex snapping, however instead of using the curser to drag the object I used the touchscreen on my laptop to drag/snap the object into place.

I appreciate this is not a solution for everyone but it might help those with touchscreen devices.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is when the mouse gets locked you should hit the "esc" key to exit the mouse lock mode.